# Unable to find command and execute

Tags: java, minecraft, eclipse-luna

I'm adding a teleport-here command to my minecraft server. Whenever I type in the command in the server, 
nothing happens, not even an 'unkown command' message. I set the executor properly (since it's not ine the main class, like my other commands that work perfectly... and the command is registered in the plugin.yml :/ No idea what's going on... Help?
I'm using Eclipse Luna and the 1.8 spigot API.

Teleport class

```
package me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.Main;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.managers.MessageManager;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class Teleport implements CommandExecutor {

    public static HashMap<UUID, Integer> tpa = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
    public static HashMap<UUID, Integer> tph = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
    public static HashMap<UUID, UUID> tpaccept = new HashMap<UUID, UUID>();

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tp")) {

            if (sender.hasPermission("sm.tp.tp")) {

                if (args.length == 0) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 1) {

                    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                        MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "The console connot teleport! Specify a second player!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    Player p = (Player) sender;

                    Player target = null;
                    for (Player test : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        if (test.getName().equals(args[0])) {
                            target = test;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (target == null) {
                        MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Either that player doesn't exist or he isn't online!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    MessageManager.getInstance().good(p, "You have been teleported to " + target.getName());
                    p.teleport(target);
                    MessageManager.getInstance().info(target, p.getName() + " has teleported to you!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args.length == 2) {

                    Player target = null;
                    for (Player test : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        if (test.getName().equals(args[0])) {
                            target = test;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Player target1 = null;
                    for (Player test1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        if (test1.getName().equals(args[1])) {
                            target1 = test1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (target == null || target1 == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "One of the players doesn't exist or isn't online!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    target.teleport(target1);
                    MessageManager.getInstance().info(target, target1.getName() + " was teleported to you by " + sender.getName() + ".");
                    MessageManager.getInstance().info(target1, "You were teleported to " + target.getName() + " by " + sender.getName() + ".");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " has been teleported to " + target1.getName() + ".");
                }

                if (args.length > 2) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Too many arguments!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Unfortunately you can't do that.");
            return true;

        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpall")) {

            if (sender.hasPermission("sm.tp.tpall")) {

                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "The console can't teleport players to him!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args.length > 0) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Too many arguments!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player p = (Player) sender;

                for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    player.teleport(p);
                    MessageManager.getInstance().info(player, p.getName() + " has teleported everyone to him.");
                }

                MessageManager.getInstance().good(p, "Everyone one the server was teleported to you!");
                return true;
            }

            MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Unfortunately you can't do that.");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpa")) {

            if (sender.hasPermission("sm.tp.tpa")) {

                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "The console cannot teleport!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player p = (Player) sender;

                if (args.length == 0) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args.length == 1) {

                    Player target = null;

                    for (Player test : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        if (test.getName().equals(args[0])) {
                            target = test;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (target == null) {
                        MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Either that player doesn't exist or he isn't online!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    tpa.put(target.getUniqueId(), 60);
                    tpaccept.put(target.getUniqueId(), p.getUniqueId());

                    if (tpa.size() == 1) {

                        new BukkitRunnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (!tpa.isEmpty()) {
                                    for (UUID uuid : tpa.keySet()) {
                                        Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);
                                        tpa.put(uuid, tpa.get(uuid) - 1);
                                        if (tpa.get(uuid) == 10) {
                                            if (player.isOnline()) {
                                                MessageManager.getInstance().info(player, "Your teleport request will expire in 10 seconds!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (tpa.get(uuid) == 0) {
                                            if (player.isOnline()) {
                                                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(player, "Your teleport request has expired!");
                                            }
                                            tpa.remove(uuid);
                                            tpaccept.remove(tpaccept.values().remove(uuid));
                                            if (tpa.isEmpty()) {
                                                this.cancel();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    this.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                        }.runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, 20L, 20L);

                    }
                    MessageManager.getInstance().custom(target, ChatColor.YELLOW + "Player " + p.getName() + " has requested to teleport to you! Use  " + ChatColor.YELLOW + ChatColor.BOLD + "/tpaccept" + ChatColor.RESET + ChatColor.YELLOW + " to teleport him!");
                    return true;
                }

                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Too many arguments!");
                return true;
            }

            MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Unfortunately you can't do that.");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tphere")) {

            if (sender.hasPermission("sm.tp.tph")) {

                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "The console cannot teleport!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player p = (Player) sender;

                if (args.length == 0) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }

                if (args.length == 1) {

                    Player target = null;

                    for (Player test : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        if (test.getName().equals(args[0])) {
                            target = test;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (target == null) {
                        MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Either that player doesn't exist or he isn't online!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    tph.put(target.getUniqueId(), 60);
                    tpaccept.put(target.getUniqueId(), p.getUniqueId());

                    if (tph.size() == 1) {

                        new BukkitRunnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (!tph.isEmpty()) {
                                    for (UUID uuid : tph.keySet()) {
                                        Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid);
                                        tph.put(uuid, tph.get(uuid) - 1);
                                        if (tph.get(uuid) == 10) {
                                            if (player.isOnline()) {
                                                MessageManager.getInstance().info(player, "Your teleport request will expire in 10 seconds!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (tph.get(uuid) == 0) {
                                            if (player.isOnline()) {
                                                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(player, "Your teleport request has expired!");
                                            }
                                            tph.remove(uuid);
                                            tpaccept.remove(tpaccept.values().remove(uuid));
                                            if (tph.isEmpty()) {
                                                this.cancel();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    this.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                        }.runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, 20L, 20L);

                    }
                    MessageManager.getInstance().custom(target, ChatColor.YELLOW + "Player " + p.getName() + " has requested to teleport to you! Use  " + ChatColor.YELLOW + ChatColor.BOLD + "/tpaccept" + ChatColor.RESET + ChatColor.YELLOW + " to teleport him!");
                    return true;
                }

                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Too many arguments!");
                return true;
            }

            MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Unfortunately you can't do that.");
            return true;
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpaccept")) {

            if (sender.hasPermission("sm.tp.tpa")) {

                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "The console cannot teleport!");
                    return true;
                }

                Player p = (Player) sender;

                if (args.length == 0) {
                    if (tpa.containsKey(p.getUniqueId()) || tpaccept.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                        Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(tpaccept.get(p.getUniqueId()));
                        target.teleport(p);
                        tpaccept.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        tpa.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        return true;
                    } else if (tpaccept.containsKey(p.getUniqueId()) || tpaccept.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
                        Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(tpaccept.get(p.getUniqueId()));
                        target.teleport(p);
                        tpaccept.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        tpa.remove(p.getUniqueId());
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "You don't have any active requests!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                MessageManager.getInstance().severe(p, "Too many arguments!");
                return true;
            }

            MessageManager.getInstance().severe(sender, "Unfortunately you can't do that.");
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

main class

```
package me.Zahachos.ServerManager;

import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.Freeze;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.HealFeed;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.KickBan;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.Mute;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.Spawn;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.Teleport;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.commands.Warp;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.listeners.JoinLeave;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.listeners.OnDeath;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.listeners.OnReconnect;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.managers.ConfigManager;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.util.Cooldown;
import me.Zahachos.ServerManager.util.utilReloadSave;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public static Main plugin = null;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        ConfigManager.getInstance().setup(this);

        getCommand("heal").setExecutor(new HealFeed());
        getCommand("feed").setExecutor(new HealFeed());
        getCommand("regenerate").setExecutor(new HealFeed());
        getCommand("tp").setExecutor(new Teleport());
        getCommand("tpall").setExecutor(new Teleport());
        getCommand("tpa").setExecutor(new Teleport());
        getCommand("tph").setExecutor(new Teleport());
        getCommand("tpaccept").setExecutor(new Teleport());
        getCommand("freeze").setExecutor(new Freeze());
        getCommand("warp").setExecutor(new Warp());
        getCommand("setwarp").setExecutor(new Warp());
        getCommand("delwarp").setExecutor(new Warp());
        getCommand("unmute").setExecutor(new Mute());
        getCommand("mute").setExecutor(new Mute());
        getCommand("tempmute").setExecutor(new Mute());
        getCommand("tempban").setExecutor(new KickBan());
        getCommand("pardon").setExecutor(new KickBan());
        getCommand("ban").setExecutor(new KickBan());
        getCommand("kick").setExecutor(new KickBan());
        getCommand("spawn").setExecutor(new Spawn());
        getCommand("setspawn").setExecutor(new Spawn());
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new JoinLeave(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Freeze(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new OnReconnect(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new KickBan(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Mute(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new OnDeath(), this);
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("[" + this.getDescription().getName() + "] Has been enabled!");
        plugin = this;

        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Cooldown.handleCooldowns();
            }
        }, 1L, 1L);

        utilReloadSave.loadBans();
        utilReloadSave.loadMutes();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Basic is Disabled!");

        utilReloadSave.saveMutes();
        utilReloadSave.saveBans();

    }
}
```

plugin.yml

```
name: ServerManager
main: me.Zahachos.ServerManager.Main
authors: [Zahachos, KarateMan]
version: 0.02
description: This manages the Zaphno's Network.

commands:

    heal:
        usage: /<command> [player]
        aliases: [health, gethealth]
        description: Heal yourself and others.

    feed:
        usage: /<command> [player]
        aliases: [food, getfood, hunger]
        description: Feed yourself and others.

    regenerate:
        usage: /<command> [player]
        aliases: [regen, regeneration]
        description: Heal and feed yourself and others.

    tp:
        usage: /<command> [player] [player2]
        aliases: [regen, regeneration]
        description: Teleport to a player, or another player to one.

    tpall:
        usage: /<command>
        aliases: [teleportall, teleporteveryone]
        description: Teleport everyone to you.    

    tpa:
        usage: /<command> [player]
        aliases: [askteleport]
        description: Ask a player to teleport to him.

    tph:
        usage: /<command> [player]
        aliases: [teleporthere, teleporth]
        description: Ask a player to teleport them to you.

    tpaccept:
        usage: /<command>
        aliases: [teleportaccept, acceptteleport]
        description: Accepts the last teleport request.

    freeze:
        usage: /<command> [username]
        aliases: [freezeplayer]
        description: Freeze or unfreeze a player!

    warp:
        usage: /<command> [warp_name]
        description: Teleport to a saved location!

    setwarp:
        usage: /<command> [warp_name]
        description: Set a warp location!

    delwarp:
        usage: /<command> [warp_name]
        aliases: [deletewarp]
        description: Delete a warp!

    mute:
        usage: /<command> [username] [duration] [reason]
        aliases: [muteplayer]
        description: Temporarily mute a player!

    tempmute:
        usage: /<command>
        aliases: [muteplayer]
        description: Mute a player!

    unmute:
        usage: /<command> [username]
        aliases: [unmuteplayer]
        description: Unmute a player!

    tempban:
        usage: /<command> [username] [duration] [reason]
        aliases: [tempbanplayer]
        description: Temporarily ban a player!

    pardon:
        usage: /<command> [username]
        aliases: [pardonplayer, unban]
        description: Pardon/Unban a player!

    ban:
        usage: /<command> [username] [reason]
        aliases: [setbanned, banplayer]
        description: Permanently ban a player!

    kick:
        usage: /<command> [username] [reason]
        aliases: [setbanned, banplayer]
        description: Kick a player!

    spawn:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Go to the server spawn!

    setspawn:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Set the server spawn!


permissions:

    sm.tp.*:
        description: Use all tp commands!
        children:
            sm.tp.tph: true
            sm.tp.tpa: true
            sm.tp.tp: true
            sm.tp.tpall: true
        default: op

    sm.health.*:
        description: Use all health commands!
        children:
            sm.health.heal: true
            sm.health.feed: true
            sm.health.regen: true
        default: op

    sm.mute.*:
        description: Use all mute commands!
        children:
            sm.mute.mute: true
            sm.mute.unmute: true
            sm.mute.canChat: true
            sm.mute.tempmute: true
        default: op

    sm.ban.*:
        description: Use all ban commands!
        children:
            sm.ban.pardon: true
            sm.ban.ban: true
            sm.ban.kick: true
            sm.ban.tempban: true
        default: op

    sm.warp.*:
        description: Use all warp commands!
        children:
            sm.warp.set: true
            sm.warp.warp: true
            sm.warp.delete: true
        default: op


    sm.heath.heal:
        default: op
        description: Heal a player!

    sm.heath.feed:
        default: op
        description: Feed a player!

    sm.heath.regen:
        default: op
        description: Heal and feed a player!    

    sm.tp.tp:
        default: op
        description: Teleport to a player, or another player to one!    

    sm.tp.tpall:
        default: op
        description: Teleport everyone to you!    

    sm.tp.tph:
        default: op
        description: Ask a player to teleport them to you.      

    sm.tp.tpa:
        default: op
        description: Teleport only if a player accepts!

    sm.mute.mute:
        default: op
        description: Mute a player!

    sm.mute.unmute:
        default: op
        description: Unmute a player!

    sm.mute.canChat:
        default: op
        description: Sets if a muted player can chat!

    sm.ban.tempban:
        default: op
        description: Temporarily ban a player!

    sm.ban.pardon:
        default: op
        description: Pardon/Unban a player!

    sm.ban.ban:
        default: op
        description: Permanently ban a player!

    sm.ban.kick:
        default: op
        description: Kick a player!

    sm.mute.tempmute:
        default: op
        description: Temporarily mute a player!

    sm.freeze:
        default: op
        description: Freeze or unfreeze a player!

    sm.warp.warp:
        default: op
        description: Teleport to a saved location!

    sm.warp.set:
        default: op
        description: Set a warp location!

    sm.warp.delete:
        default: op
        description: Delete a warp!

    sm.setspawn:
        default: op
        description: Set the server spawn!
```

Comment: You need to show the relevant code.

Comment: @August There isn't any code to show I mean, I'm not gonna post my project on here. You could at least tell me some common mistakes.

Comment: No one wants to blindly guess what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said, then the problem must lie within your plugin file, not in your plugin.ym or main class. Now, as you haven't provided what command it is, and the code of the plugin, then it is impossible to help you any further.

The server is most likely executing the command, and then nothing happens simply because the plugin itself is malfunctioning--not the server. *Start your debugging with your plugin.*